# How to setup Google IAP between 2 Google App Engine Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I have a frontend project and a backend project. These are 2 separate app engine projects.

Setting up IAP on both is not problem but when my frontend project tries to call the backend project it is blocked.

Is there anyway to have access allowed to the backend project when the user passes the frontend IAP ? or do I have to leave the backend project without IAP enabled ?

Comment: Why the front end and the backend are in different project? In addition, when you mean front-end, do you mean JS/html code ?

Comment: Yes its React frontend, backend is on another instance so that its scalable

Answer (score 0):

You have to programmatically invoke (make the call using an OIDC token) to the backend from your front end. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-python) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are misunderstandings. Let me clarify.

Firstly, your App Engine is highly scalable in a single project. Instead of having several projects with several App Engine, you should have only one project, with a single App Engine and multiple services.

Default is usually used for the frontend part. You can use an API service for your backend, or name it as you wish.

Like that, the whole website will be protected by the same IAP context. Like that, no issue as you have before, it's the same IAP cookies and the API calls should not create issues.

---

Secondly, keep in mind that your JS code runs in the client browser, not on App Engine; App Engine only serves the static files, that's all. All the rest of the computation is performed locally.

Comment: Can you show a config Which does this split service on one app engine ? Also I have more than one frontend project which consumes the same API.

Comment: You can serve all that frontend on the same App Engine, but over different services. Instead of deploying in different projects, deploy your services in the same project. Use the keyword `service` to set the name of your service. More detail here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python

Comment: Does this not become a nightmare for debugging issues ?

Comment: Why? You have 1 log per services, nothing change!

Comment: And how about custom domain names for each service ? From what I can see you can only add one domain name per app engine instance

Comment: Ah yes. But for entreprise grade experience, I recommend to avoid custom domain and to prefer a Load Balancer. You can put your App Engine services as backend (serverless NEG) and multiple domain on your  Load Balancer frontend.